# regex: how to stop on no alpha or end of line char?

Tags: regex

My goal is to match both:

```
25 place de la paix
24 place de la guerre. Do not continue after .
26 place de la foi !do not continue after !
```

Should give 3 results:

```
25 place de la paix
24 place de la guerre
26 place de la foi
```

I use:

```
   /\d+\splace.*[^a-z\s]/iU
```

which works fine for

```
24 place de la guerre.
```

Since it stopps at a none alpha numeric char "."

I would like to stop the regex on no alpha OR at end of line char: any idea ?

I tried with

```
/\d+\splace.*[^a-z\s\n]/iU

/\d+\splace.*[^a-z\s\r]/iU
```

Comment: the first non-alpha in your string is a space?

Comment: Are those two different lines ? If yes then is this supposed to return two matches ( 1st and 2nd ) line ?

Comment: I mean: no alphanumeric excluding space \s

Comment: @noob: `g` isn't really a modifier. In many implementations, the method determines if the search is global or not. For example, in PHP you have `preg_match` and `preg_match_all`.

Answer (score 1):

`\s` includes space, tabs and line breaks. That's why when you used `\s` in `[^a-z\s]`. It also negates matching on new line. You can use this:

`/\d+ place de la \w+/`

to match all of these:

25 place de la paix

24 place de la guerre

26 place de la foi

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `.*` after `place`. You can just use `[a-z\s]*` to match what you want:

```
/\b\d+\s+place[a-z\s]*/i
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sS3zJ7/1)

Or else use `negative lookahead` to stop when you encounter first non-letter, non-space character:

```
/\b\d+\s+place.*?(?=[^a-z\s]|$)/mi
```

Answer (score 0):

use a non-capturing with spaces followed by alpha characters:

```
/\d+\h+place(?:\h+[a-z]+)*/i
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/pL9xM6/1)

Note: most of the time, the U modifier is totally useless.

Comment: Problem is: it matches also "25 place de la paix!!" : it shoudl stop ON no alpha char which it does not in your case